# Using FatJarRouter when upgrading camel-spring-boot from 2.18 to 2.19

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, apache-camel, executable-jar

I was hoping I could get some clarification on a little problem we've been having.

Our project has been using a combination of camel and spring boot. We've been using a bunch of Camel modules, all version '2.18.3'.

Notably, we have been using the Camel module 'camel-spring-boot-starter', which depends on the 'camel-spring-boot' module which gives us the FatJarRouter class that we have been extending on our main class.

Recently, I've been trying to upgrade the main dependencies in our project, including Camel and spring boot. I've upgraded 'spring-boot-starter-parent' to version '1.5.4.RELEASE' and I've upgraded our Camel modules to '2.19.1'.

However, surprisingly, we found that the FatJarRouter class was no longer on our class path! I've tried looking through the change notes for 2.19, as well as Googling for more information but I can't find anything that mentions any change of procedure for using FatJars in Camel Spring Boot applications.

So my questions is this: Does anyone know if FatJarRouter has been removed or merely moved in Camel 2.19? If it has been moved, could you please point me in the direction of which artifact now holds it? If it has been removed, does anyone have any information on how FatJar applications should be tackled in Camel 1.19?

Thankyou for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its removed, just use regular `RouteBuilder` classes, see the existing examples for how to use Camel with Spring Boot: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples#examples